# Upsert document with NEST (ElasticSearch)

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm new to NEST and ElasticSearch and have to index some documents but encounters some issues when it comes to upserting.

Each document has an ID.

When pushing a document with a certain ID, if the index already contains a document with this ID, I'd like to replace the doc. And if no document with this ID exists, it would simply be about inserting the document.

At the moment, I'm using `client.IndexAsync` but it generates duplicates. And `client.UpdateAsync` requires an existing ID if I understood it well.

I found [this in ES documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#upserts), but there's nothing related in NEST.
Do I have to use the low level client or is there something I'm missing in NEST?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share your index mapping because by default `IndexAsync` works they way you are describing, from docs `Adds a JSON document to the specified data stream or index and makes it searchable. If the target is an index and the document already exists, the request updates the document and increments its version.` [Docs link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#docs-index_).

Comment: Your comment made me look if something was wrong during the insert operation and Ids were generated in a wrong way and prevented upserting. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hey @Rob, the second note is interesting, i think it's the updated info, here it is; You cannot use the index API to send update requests for existing documents to a data stream. See Update documents in a data stream by query and Update or delete documents in a backing index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was in fact related to wrongly generated IDs which prevented upserting.